# EXCEL Search Column in another Workbook by Text in Column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two workbooks open in a file. My first workbook is "Trades" and my second is "Searches". I want to search Column A of Trades (which has one ID) against Column E of Searches (which has 0 to 50 IDs; where if there is over 1 ID, they are separated by commas). So, essentially, I want to know if the IDs of Column A of Trades were searched.

I tried using:

```
 =COUNTIF(Searches!E:E,"*Trades!A1:A11412*")
```

and

```
 =COUNTIF(Searches!E:E,Trades!A:A)
```

and

```
 =LOOKUP(REPT("z",255),CHOOSE({1,2},"ANOTHER VALUE",LOOKUP(1000,FIND($E$1:$E$11412,Trades!A:A),$E$1:$E$11412))) [The data is rows 1 - 11412]
```

Thanks so much!

Comment: If you could, please provide a dropbox or copy.com link to your workbook (or similar if confidentiality is an issue) so that we can get a better idea of what exactly you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Great, thank you. Can you clarify what your goal is? Is it essentially a vlookup function? Or are you trying to see if you have duplicate IDs in each worksheet?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? expected results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in `sheet Trades` in cell **`J2`** and copy down until the last cell:

```
=IF(ISNA(LOOKUP(2^15,FIND(A2,Searches!$E$2:$E$2000),Searches!$E$2:$E$2000)),"NOT FOUND","FOUND")
```

let me know if this is what you want.

here it is: 
**it returns the row number**:

```
=MATCH("*"&A2&"*",Searches!$E$1:$E$2000,0)
```

### Update

You can combine the two like this, if found, it will give you the row number, if not, it will return "NOT FOUND":

```
=IF(ISNA(LOOKUP(2^15,FIND(A2,Searches!$E$1:$E$2000),Searches!$E$1:$E$2000)),"NOT FOUND",MATCH("*"&A2&"*",Searches!$E$1:$E$2000,0))
```

let me know if it still works for you.

### 2nd update

Actually you'd better do it with a vba code than formula. However here is the formula to return all the hits for your query.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(ROW(Searches!$E$2:$E$2000),SMALL(IF(ISNUMBER(FIND($A2,Searches!$E$2:$E$2000)),ROW(Searches!$E$2:$E$2000)-ROW(Searches!$E$2)+1),COLUMNS($L2:L2))),"")
```

Try this in **J2** in ***trades*** sheet, and then so press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd> to calculate the formula. This is an array formula. Then copy and drag the formula to the right of the **J2**, drag it until let's say **M2** and then select your **J2:M2** and drag it down until the last row of your data sheet, but just for the sake of getting to know the formula, copy it down until the 100th row first, and let excel calculate and see how it goes. Be reminded that these array formulas will take ages to calculate!!! that is why you need a vba code to do it!

But if you have more than 4 hits per query, then you need to extend your formulas beyong **M2**, maybe go until Z2 or something, it is upto you to determine the maximum of hits that you might reach per query.

Comment: so you expect to see a sequence of rows (list of hits) for each query? right? say for ABCDEF123 you want to see, 21, 23, 154, 650 which correspond to the row numbers where the string is found? right?